# Create torrent application with command line or PHP script

Tags: php, command-line, bittorrent

How can I create torrent file with PHP? Now I use mktorrent for windows, but sometimes its create torrent file that I can't open with uTorrent.

OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking here: https://github.com/christeredvartsen/php-bittorrent

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Torrent RW](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4896-PHP-Create-and-parse-Torrent-files.html).

> This class can be used to create and
>   parse torrent files. It can read a
>   torrent file and parse it to extract
>   metadata. The class can also create a
>   new torrent file and announce it in a
>   given tracker server.

Also, [TorrentFlux](http://www.torrentflux.com/) look like good solution (but for *nix only), and I've actually never tried it.

Anyways, you can make your own class to deal with torrent files, if you know how torrent file's structure looks like.